# Google Colab "intelligent code completion" running really slow

Tags: google-colaboratory

When trying to code in google colab, the code completion works really slow. Anyone knows how to fix this?
I would say it takes about a good "1 and a half" to 2 seconds before any suggetions are made.
Workflow = super ruined
Running colab on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to fix it.

In colab press tools -> settings -> editor -> scroll down -> "Code diagnostics" -> turn it off.

Fixed my problem.